# How to find and replace a text in comments using JQuery

Tags: jquery

I would like to search **only comments** in Javascript, html and CSS using JQuery. Is this possible?

I will extend my questions:
In javascript console I would like to find all comments which are actually loaded in DOM. I need this to find out if any important messages are not sent to client. Usually developers love to add comments like: TODO: we will check do this later. And during semi-automatic tests I would like to ensure that all such comments will not be download to client browser.

Comment: Not possible _without looking at your code_

Comment: @pXL what code should I add? example of comment in Javascript?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes. Iterate through all nodes (recursively for element nodes) and check if the node's `nodeType` property is equal to 8 (`COMMENT_NODE`)

Comment: I need to check also JS and CSS.

Comment: I have to ask... why? Comments should NEVER serve any purpose other than to describe to the programmer what a particular thing does...

Comment: I would like be SURE that there is nothing more than small description, and there isn't any important information in comments

Comment: Okay... why can't you just search your source file for comments and edit them there?

Comment: How should I did this? Including fact that non important comments are removed Yahoo minifier.